# get a blank white screen with only app.vue items but not other component

Tags: ios, vue.js, cordova, cordova-ios

i have an app build on vuejs and build with cordova. after i cordova build ios it successfully build the app but when i cordova emulate ios it is only showing app.vue components but not other components. the app.vue content is nav.vue. it only show the nav bar and make the other white screen. can someone please help me to solve this problem.

```
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />

     <splash src="res/screen/ios/icon.png" />
</platform>

<access origin="about:*" />
<allow-navigation href="about:" />

<access origin="tel:" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:" launch-external="yes" />

<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
```

this is my config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the Safari Developer Tools on Mac to connect to your test device and check out the JavaScript console. Often times you will see the error there. On Android you can do this with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question. i solve this problem by just change the vue route history mode in to hash mode
like shown below

```
const router = new VueRouter({
                   mode: "hash",
                   base: process.env.BASE_URL,
                   routes,
               });
```

and add the below code in **vue.config.js** file

```
devServer:{
    https:false
}
```